# How to pass maps to functions in elixir?

Tags: elixir, pattern-matching

I'm iterating over a list with the structure

```
[
  %{color: "green", index: 0},
  %{color: "blue", index: 1}
]
```

and I want to pass this to a function but I getting errors saying: `no function clause matching`

```
def myFunction(%{color: color, index: index}) do
  IO.inspect(color)
end
```

what am i doing wrong to pattern match on this?

Comment: The bit *after* `no function clause matching` tells you what you passed to the function and what it expected instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything right, assuming you pass *each* element of the list to the function, not the whole list. That might be done, e. g. by iteration through list elements as shown below.

```elixir
defmodule M do
  @data [%{color: "green", index: 0}, %{color: "blue", index: 1}]
  
  def my_function(%{color: color, index: index}) do
    IO.inspect(color)
  end
  
  def test, do: Enum.each(@data, &my_function/1)
end
```

And then

```elixir
M.test

"green"
"blue"
```

*Sidenote:* in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) we use snakecase, not camelcase for naming.

Answer (score 0):

> what am i doing wrong to pattern match on this?

You defined your function to take a map as the single argument:

```
def myFunction(%{color: color, index: index}) do
```

yet the data structure you listed in your post is...a list:

```
[
  %{color: "green", index: 0},
  %{color: "blue", index: 1}
]
```

A list is not a map, and because you did not define any function clause that takes a list as an argument, you cannot past a list to the function.

You could do this:

a.ex:

```
defmodule A do
  def go do
    colors = [
      %{color: "green", index: 0},
      %{color: "blue", index: 1}
    ]

    display(colors)
  end

  def display([rgb|rest]) do
    IO.puts "color is: #{rgb.color}"
    display(rest)
  end
  def display([]) do
    :ok
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(4)> c("a.ex")
[A]

iex(5)> A.go     
color is: green
color is: blue
:ok
```